# Excel formula trouble—need to copy values of adjacent column, but at every 6th row, double the copied value. Combining these 2 has gotten me lost

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently I've managed to copy the values in column I to column L using `=OFFSET(I5,0,0,1)`

But I'd like to combine this with another formula somehow...

Values in column I :

```
0
200
150
250
430
100
0
250
220
350
90
0
```

Values to be copied to column L :

```
0
200
150
250
430
**200**
0
250
220
350
**180**
0
```

I realize that my row is being written horizontally here but it is easier to understand this way, I think.

I am new to excel formulas and thus why I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this formula can help you:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),6)=0,A1*2,A1)
```

[image]

Comment: I had just figured it out myself! LOL =IF(MOD(CELL("row",I5),6)=3,I5*2,I5).  THANKS! I'm giving you the Answer! Thanks for the quick response too!